# org collapses with three dots ... after helm-org-in-buffer-headings jump

Tags: org-mode

I use helm-org-in-buffer-headings.  You can see the three dots ... in the picture.
[image]

The desired result is:
[image]

The three dots part is expanded.

Comment: Have you tried `org-reveal` when on the "go build" heading?

Comment: @AndrewSwann . use org-reveal indeed unfolds the ...  Is it possible to tell org not to hide it at first?

Comment: You can tell org to not fold headings when you open a file by setting `org-startup-folded` to `nil`.

Comment: I don't use helm.  Can you explain how you get to the first display.  There may be some command you can advise so that it runs `org-reveal` automatically.

Comment: @AndrewSwann thank you very much.  I feel org-reveal is close to the answer.  I will dig more into helm.